# How to configure a coder to generate a constant pointer to a constant variable?

Tags: simulink, data-dictionary, embedded-coder

My objective is to configure the Simulink Coder/Embedded Coder to generate for global parameters the following result:

```
extern const real32_T* const globalParameter;
```

Using the Custom Storage Class Designer tool ([cscdesigner](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/design-custom-storage-classes-and-memory-sections.html)) I managed to partially achieve my goal, currently I generate the following result:

```
extern const real32_T* globalParameter;
```

How can I can I configure the coder to generate the missing part i.e., the constant variable:

```
const globalParameter
```

Thanks for your support!

Best regards,

Luis

Answer (score 0):

You can always use TLC for your CSC, for further customizations in case the normal options do not provide you the options you need. From the top of my head I do not know if what you want is possible using "normal" CSC.